# How to handle admin only GAE-Datastore updates

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, backend, google-cloud-endpoints

I've created my first App Engine project. I'm using cloud endpoints and the datastore to provide a backend for a mobile app. The users will only use the existing content, they won't have a way to alterate the datastore content.

So the content of the datastore will be managed by me exclusively. I have less than 10 kinds of entity, and around 5000 objects. These objects will need a partial update approximately twice a month.

To generate these objects on my side, I use few local sqlite databases and I also aggregate some information from the web.

My question is what is the best way to do those datastore updates? My first thought was to use endpoints for the insert/update operations, and secure them to be accessible only by me. Then, twice a month I would use my "admin client", to generate the new stuff, and use the secure web services to update the datastore content.

But I wonder if there is a more appropriate way for this. Especially in terms of efficiency and data consistency. What happens if a user is asking for the content during the update process, he will have something partially up to date.

Maybe I could use another API that I'm not aware of? Or simply use some sort of script on the app engine side?

**EDIT**

One of my `Entity` has few `EmbeddedEntities`. It is not mandatory for me, but I figured that it would be less expensive that way to retrieve them, and I don't need to access them from elsewhere.

But with this model, I can't find how to use the bulkloader to upload my data, nor the RemoteApi. In both cases, the embeddedEntities are not filled: I have `<missing>` for every fields of the embedded entities in the `DataViewer`, and nothing returned in my endpoints. If I use my insert endpoint it works. Also, to be clear, despite the embedded entities, everything works.

*My Model*

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private MyEmbeddedEntity embeddedEntity;
    ...
    @Embedded
    public MyEmbeddedEntity getEmbeddedEntity() {
        return embeddedEntity;
    }
}
```

*RemoteApi*

```
EmbeddedEntity embeddedEntity = new EmbeddedEntity();
embeddedEntity.setProperty("name", "testEmbedded");

Entity entity = new Entity("MyEntity", 1L);
entity.setProperty("name", "test");
entity.setProperty("embeddedEntity", embeddedEntity);

...

datastore.put(entity);
```

*Bulkloader*

I have generated the yaml config with create_bulkloader_config. I set the simplexml connector, with a xpath_to_nodes=/list/MyEntities corresponding to the structure of my xml.

I've tried different approaches with the @Embedded annotations. I also tried with different entity Keys. If I insert an entity with my endpoint, and import the data with the bulkloader and the same yaml config, my generated xml doesn't contain the embedded entities (whereas they are visible in the DataViewer).

Comment: Have you considered using the remote_api?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bulkuploader, or write your own version of uploader (use "login: admin" in app.yaml you protect handlers).

You can use transactions (if your data model allows it) to avoid problems during update process, OR you can use temporary property like "ready: true|false" during upload process.

Comment: I have added more info on my attempts on using the remote_api and the bulkloader. For your idea about writing my own version of uploader, did you mean having a custom servlet, only accessible by me? How would I access this servlet from my computer and be authentified then? One of my requirements is to be able to make those update on the datastore, from my computer without having to write too much code. I loved the idea of the remote_api because I could do it from a simple pure java project. The bulkloader is one script to run so it's ok too.